# Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3):\mathbb{Q}$ compared to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

I have the following rather trivial question, but I can't seem to figure out.

If look at the galois group of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3):\mathbb{Q}$ then the minimal poly is $(x^2-5)^2-24$ and the roots are $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$, then in this case why can I have an automorphism sending $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$. This will permute the roots of the poly. But if you compare this to when you look at $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ then the galois group of this poly we cant have such an automorphism, and here the automorphism just change the signs, but these will work in the above case because it permutes the roots  $\pm \sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{3}$

So my question is, can we have $\sqrt2 \mapsto -\sqrt{3}$ be an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)+\sqrt(3)):\mathbb{Q}$?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two field extensions are the same
$$
\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})
$$
so the same is the Galois group. No automorphism can send $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{3}$, because otherwise it would send $2$ to $3$.

You're making a bit of confusion: $(x^2-2)(x^2-3)$ is not an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Of course!! I completely missed that. Thank you very much